# Как записывать дозаписывать файл в определенное место? C++

Tags: c++, c, файлы, config

Допустим у меня есть файл в нем данные записаны вот так:

```
void create()
{
   std::ofstream write_in_file("file.conf");
   write_in_file << "id1 = " << id1 << std::endl;
   write_in_file << "id2 = " << id2 << std::endl;
   write_in_file << "id3 = " << id3 << std::endl;
   write_in_file << "id4 = " << id4 << std::endl;
}
```

Допустим мне снова надо открыть этот файл и поменять, скажем id3 присвоить туда что-то другое, как это можно сделать средствами std?

Comment: если записи одинакового размера - да. Если разного, то обычно нужно прочитать весь файл, изменить и записать по новой. Либо читать по одной записи и переписывать в новый файл

Comment: @KoVadim не совсем если четно понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: вычитать файл и перезаписать?

Comment: Текстовые файлы обычно прочитываются целиком и парсятся. Т.е., данные из них извлекаются в соответствующие переменные и структуры программы. Так что стандартный порядок действий примерно такой: 1) загружаем текст из файла "file.conf" в некую динамическую строку; 2) распарсиваем эту строку и извлекаем значения ключей; 3) изменяем нужные ключи; 4) записываем файл обратно. Если вы кодите под винду и вас интересует практический результат, а не процесс, то можете воспользоваться готовым API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofileint